# Reusable Layouts with Fragments through TabLayout/ViewPager

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am trying to re-create my old app because I lost my project files entirely. I was able to get some XML UI files through apk-decompile but now I am stuck in a rather complicated situation. I am trying to create dynamic fragments through `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. As I remember the last time I did this same thing I did not create a whole bunch of layout files for this and the UI files I recovered support my thinking.

Anyway, right now I am using one base_layout_file which holds my TabLayout and ViewPager and then in every instance of my fragment I load a single layout file which has a RecyclerView in it to show some data in every fragment.

I remember using this code to generate several Tabs and their layouts and they worked fine but right now this doesn't work. It kind of replaces all the data in every `RecyclerView`, and at most shows only one `RecylerView` with data and all the others are empty, maybe because they have same IDs. But it did not happen in the past so I am not sure how to proceed from here.

What is the meaning of re-usable UI here if I am not able to reuse the same UI for multiple fragments. I am sure I am creating a new Fragment for each data-collection.

The code is as follows:

```
var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.main_tabs_viewpager);
var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.main_tabs_header);
tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
var data = await Web.GetSchedule(); // a Dictionary<type> here
var tabsAdapter = new PageTabsAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
viewPager.Adapter = tabsAdapter;
if (data != null)
{
    foreach (var item in data)
}
tabsAdapter.AddTab(new TitleFragment() { Title = item.Key, Fragmnet = new MainTabs(DataEnum.MainTabsType.Schedule, item.Value) });
```

Tabs_Adapter:

```
// TABS ADAPTER

    public class TitleFragment
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Fragment MyFragment { get; set; }
    }


    private List<TitleFragment> Fragments { get; set; }

        public PageTabsAdapter(FragmentManager manager) : base(manager/*, BehaviorResumeOnlyCurrentFragment*/)
        {
            Fragments = new List<TitleFragment>();
        }

        public override int Count => Fragments == null ? 0 : Fragments.Count;

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return Fragments[position].MyFragment;
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(Fragments[position].Title);
        }

        public bool AddTab(TitleFragment fragment)
        {
            if (Fragments == null || fragment == null) return false;

            Fragments.Add(fragment);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
```

Fragment Class (whose instance is recreated):

```
// Fragment Class
        public MainTabs(DataEnum.MainTabsType tabType)
        {
            this.tabType = tabType;
        }

        public MainTabs(DataEnum.MainTabsType tabType, List<CalenderScheduleList> items) : this(tabType)
        {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            if (inflater == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inflater));
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            if (tabType == DataEnum.MainTabsType.TVSchedule)
            {
                return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.tv_schedule_list, container, false);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            if (tabType == DataEnum.MainTabsType.TVSchedule)
            {
                recyclerView = Activity.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.schedule_rv);
                emptyView = Activity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.schedule_emptytext);
                emptyView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            LoadDataForType();
        }

        private void LoadDataForType()
        {
            switch (tabType)
            {
                case DataEnum.MainTabsType.Schedule:
                    var scheduleAdapter = new EpisodesAdapter<CalenderScheduleList>(items, tabType, emptyView);
                    recyclerView.SetAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
                    scheduleAdapter.ItemClick += delegate
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Item clicked", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    };
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Layout Files:

```
// main_tabs
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tabParent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs_header"
        android:elevation="@dimen/tabs_elevation"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs_viewpager"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>


// base_layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
       layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_tabs"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/schedule_loading"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


// recycler_view

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/schedule_rv"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_data_view"
        android:id="@+id/schedule_emptytext"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong? I have tried to search for this particular issue but have not found anything useful yet. I am using Support Libraries and I also tried the new AndroidX libraries with the same results. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition with Xamarin for Android.

Edit: More info added

Edit: Issue GIF

Please notice the data changes when the new tab gets selected but the tab has no data in it.

[image]

Comment: I test your codes only change the data to a `List<string>`, it works for me.All fragments use the UI of `MainTabs` .i could not understand waht do you mean  `not able to reuse the same UI for multiple fragments`.Maybe you could show a screenshot to describe it

Comment: I mean I am not able to see the data. It only loads other fragment's data into current tab and all the other tabs are empty. When I swipe through the tabs some tabs show data and then data disappears for some reason and it does not load data. I have set breakpoints within the adapters and they dont hit most of the times.
I think I'll retest with a sample project and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I created another test project and on my phone, which is running Android 9 API 28, I am still having the same issue. Some tabs show data and some don't. I am gonna try to create a Virtual Device and test further.

Comment: how many tabs do you have？

Comment: Actually around 11 or so but in my test-project I created 4 and same effect was there. I think partially problem may be VS2019. It's been crashing a lot lately.

Comment: try to change your FragmentPageAdapter to FragmentStatePageAdapter which your adapter extend

Comment: I have created a private Git for this issue: https://github.com/ahmar20/com.aa.tvshows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my situation above is twofold here:

If you look at the code above you can see that I am returning an inflated layout in the `OnCreateView` function of the Fragment class (good so far) and then I am finding my views in the `OnViewCreated` function through the parent `Activity` and **this is wrong from Android's point of view and you should Never do that.** I learned it the hard way.

As it turns out, you should find your views through the inflated view and possibly find them in the `OnCreateView` function and everything works as expected now that I have changed the code.

So above code in `OnCreateView` would look like:

```
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.your_xml, container, false);
recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.main_popular_shows_rv);
emptyView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.main_popular_shows_emptytext);
loadingView = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.main_popular_shows_loading);
return view;
```

I hope it helps someone along the way.